# Сохранения состояния отсчета в Android

Tags: java, android, textview, таймер, onsaveinstancestate

У меня идет обратный отсчет, который отображается в TextView. При смене ориентации текст в TextView становится указанным в xml разметке. Можно сохранить текст при вызове метода OnSaveInstanceState, но если повернуть экран на 25 секунде, то она только и будет отображаться. При этом обратный отсчет в системе идет и выполняет указанную функцию по окончанию... Как продолжать отсчет в TextView даже после смены ориентации экрана?

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerView.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerBanner.setText("0");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Вам нужно отсчёт делать не в активити/фрагменте, но в к-л классе, коий не уничтожается при повороте экрана. Так вам и сохранять ничего не надо и ничего не сбросится. Используйте готовые подходы - `MVP`. Например либу `Moxy` - да, надо будет относительно много кода написать, зато проблема будет решена концептуально правильно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял, буду реализовывать через отдельный класс. Спасибо

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прям сразу moxy для такого пустяка .. концептуально правильно все это можно решить инструментами Architecture Components от гугла, в частности ViewModel сохраняет состояние при пересоздании активити и все это гораздо "легче" того же moxy

Comment: @pavlofff, я исхожу из того, что вряд ли всё приложение ограничивается только этой задачей) А в этом случае всё равно надо что-то типа Moxy/Mosby etc использовать, если делать хорошо)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Со своей стороны не считаю MVP единственно правильным решением "хорошо". Я, например, не использую этот паттерн, в пользу "нативных" решений гугла и не могу сказать, что получается "не хорошо" :)

Comment: @pavlofff, я новые эти штуки от гугла не пробовал, ничего на этот счёт сказать не могу)